# How many legs does the bear have?

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge

Warning: This sounds like one you've heard before but it's not.

---

A hunter leaves his camp and heads one mile north. Scanning the horizon for prey, he spots a likely spot to the east. He walks for a half mile before spotting movement further east. He sprints the half mile only to find that whatever was there is gone. Downtrodden, he walks the one mile south back to camp. Opening the door of the hut, he begins to call out for his partner when he sees it: A live bear in the hut! Thinking quickly, he pulls out his rifle and shoots it dead. Hearing the gunshot, his partner emerges from the other room. "Hey!" he shouts, "I just captured that bear outside and brought it in here to study!" Sheepishly, the hunter admits that he probably reacted too hastily.

How many legs did the bear have?

Comment: Um, four? Have you ever seen a bear that doesn't have four legs?

Comment: 4? like any normal bear?

Comment: I would assume the inconsistency with the directions have something to do with the number of legs a bear has. Also, strictly speaking, a bear has two legs and two arms...

Comment: Well...I know where camp is. Not many bears there, though.

Comment: Hm, 1km north then 1 Mile east -> 1 Mile south won't get you back to the camp, so he must went to Yogi bear's home and shoot him dead, you bad hunter!

Comment: @Alex the traditional question uses 1 mile north and you realise he was close to the north pole or at the south pole.

Comment: @Kaine ah I still don't get how it'll change if it's at north/south pole?

Comment: @Alex http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/rescue-operation-where-is-your-partner

Comment: Not sure if I like this question given the accepted answer. As Geobits said, shooting a water bear with a rifle is unrealistic. And the stuff about where the hunter walks is completely irrelevant, right?

Comment: @kaine Ah that's the trick of the previous question, thanks!

Comment: @randal'thor I'll grant you the unrealistic bit. I could edit in that he has superhuman skill with a rifle OR I could just say it's Davy Crockett. The walking part is relevant because it limits it to the south pole and the only bears down there are water bears.

Comment: The walking part does NOT limit it to the south pole! He could be a short distance away from the north pole. I Googled to find a reference [here](http://www.mindcipher.com/puzzles/13); there's also a very good discussion of the bear problem in one of Martin Gardner's books.

Comment: @randal'thor OK, you're right if the hut is just south of the north pole such that the hunter returns to the original spot when he travels east. That's not a solution I have considered and, although I'm not a fan of such loopholes, I'll admit it exists. What's a good way to close that hole without explicitly stating where the hunter is?

Comment: @EngineerToast Would mentioning penguins or albatrosses be too big a hint? (Anyway I'm not sure if they're found actually *at* the South Pole - not much is, probably - or just in subantarctic regions.)

Comment: @randal'thor That is simular to the answer provided here that I sent to Alex above but does that take into account the 1km vs. 1 mile thing?

Comment: @kaine Not sure if I get the 1km vs. 1 mile thing actually. What's the point if all we're meant to deduce is that it's near the south pole?

Comment: @rand al'thor to me it was why it couldn't be at the north pole but now it doesnt matter...it was changed and i have no idea if that change is correct or not

Comment: @EngineerToast Wow ... that slipup has caused a lot of confusion!

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, [my bad](http://i.lvme.me/dlhc3vl.jpg). I'm distracted by actual work today.

Comment: @EngineerToast but you haven't managed to keep to your "temporary leave of absence". SE is so addictive, isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> The bear has 8 legs... it is a water bear.

I don't know why he would shoot it but I would be embarrassed too.

The camp is a short distance north of the south pole.  He walks north, walks around the pole, and then goes past the south pole on his way back to camp.  This accounts for the distance difference which can only really happen there.  Polar bears don't live at the south pole. Neither do Siberian water bears (which would be a silly guess).

Comment: He must have good eyes and a steady hand to spot and shoot something ~1mm in size with a rifle :)

Comment: @Geobits  i agree but it is the only type of bear i could come up with that has more or less than 4 legs naturally.  Thought koala but they do too.

Comment: [Tardigrades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) are legitimately terrifying in their unyielding to the elements.

Comment: Why six and not eight? See EngineerToast's link.

Comment: @JLee You're right and I ticked too quickly. I read "water bear" and I didn't process that it should be 8. Man, I am really bad at this.

Comment: @JLee that got edited out when someone added the spoilers.  I meant it to be Siberean as I was thinking of north places... regular Tardigrade probably the accurate one.

Comment: @kaine The OP wants it to be at the South Pole (although that's not directly implied by the puzzle), so Siberian water bear is out.

Comment: @kaine It is most likely not a Siberian water bear. Where is the hunter?

Comment: @EngineerToast I will edit it to a regular water bear but i wrote this answer not expecting it to be correct.

Comment: For the last portion, he would be walking North, not South.

Comment: @TheNumberOne yes but was started walking in the south direction and did not change direction. I took a little liberty there.

Comment: I think if he starts by walking a mile north, before walking around the pole by walking a mile (2x 1/2 mile), his camp must be slightly south of the north pole, not slightly north of the south pole. Otherwise the 2 half-miles he walks east wouldn't be enough to get around the pole. If he starts slightly 1 mile + a bit south of the north pole, then the 2 half miles east can get him around the pole (an arbitrary number of times).

Comment: @doug_mcclean it was changed from 1km north to 1 mile north after the answer was written.

Answer (score 3):

The bear has:

> zero legs.

If I'm a hunter, that's the only way I would sheepishly admit that an unknown live bear inside our hut was not something worth shooting. Bears are [godless killing machines](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bear&defid=1696621), and even more dangerous in small areas.

Comment: Godless klling machines: http://www.wildnatureimages.com/Grizzly_Bear_Cubs.htm

Comment: @kaine Pro tip: Don't surprise a hunter by placing wild animals in his hut, even cuddly ones ;)

Comment: Even with no legs, a regular bear could wiggle over and bite you like a 43 stone worm with razor teeth. If it got really mad, it might shoot chainsaw-wielding wasps from it maw, covering you in a swarm of pain and tears.

Comment: @EngineerToast Agreed, but it would give me a bit more time before I die to shoot it. Not much, but a chance. Then again, maybe a one-legged bear would be a bit slower, since he might try hopping instead of worming.

Answer (score 3):

Some possibilities:

- 4 legs - it's a polar bear (or any other kind of bear), artificially transported from captivity or from its natural habitat to the South Pole by persons unknown for reasons unknown.
- 2 legs - it's a [larger, hairier man who projects an image of rugged masculinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_(gay_culture)), or it's [someone on this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_(nickname)), or [someone on this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_(surname)), or [Bear Grylls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_Grylls). Or it's someone who believes that share prices are set to fall.
- 8 legs - a [water bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) as per @kaine's answer.
- A non-integer number of legs - any of the above, having suffered an injury.

It couldn't be [the Tupolev Tu-95 strategic bomber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-95), because that wouldn't fit in the hut.

Of course, it also depends what you mean by 'hut'. If the 'hut' is the Helsinki (or Hanoi) University of Technology, then it would be easily big enough for the strategic bomber.

And 'legs' is also a little bit ambiguous....

OK, I'm going to interpret the question to mean:

> How many copies of the classic soft-rock single "Legs", by ZZ Top, can you fit inside a Tupolev Tu-95 strategic bomber ('Bear') on the campus of the Helsinki  University of Technology ('HUT')?

So then the answer is clearly 35,000, and you get 35,000 copies of the B-side ("A Fool for Your Stockings") into the bargain.

Comment: You don't know how big the hut is. The bomber might fit. What about a Chicago Bear? How about a masculine homosexual man? I, too, can read the disambiguation page on Wikipedia.

Comment: Was the polar bear transported by the Dharma Initiative?

Comment: I have no proof of such, but I would suppose it would be theoretically possible for a water bear to have an extra leg or two due to some sort of genetic mutation..

Comment: +1 for hilarity (especially the share-price and non-integer parts). Welcome to the Trusted User club!

Comment: @EngineerToast, you're right of course. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still going to go with

> Four. It's still the same gorram polar bear from the other puzzle. About time someone put an end to its shenanigans.

Because

> The camp is a bit more than a mile away from the north pole. (The distance has an exact value somewhere in the vicinity of 1.16 miles; figuring it out is left as an exercise for the reader.)

This works, because

> The hunter goes one mile north, then one mile east (walking/running a full circle around the north pole, at a distance of about 0.16 miles), and then one mile south to get back to the camp.

There are other possible positions for the camp, too, but

> going around the north pole twice or more does not seem likely, given how the story is presented. Circling the pole once seems perfectly plausible, though; or at least much more so than a sudden tardigrade-slaughtering rampage.