# If Weird Al Yankovic Wrote Riddles

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, humor

When I wake up ???? ? ???? ?’? ????? ??

?’? ????? ?? ??? ??? ??? ????? ?? ???? ?? ???

When I go out ???? ? ???? ?’? ????? ??

?’? ????? ?? ??? ??? ??? ???? ????? ???? ???

If I get drunk ???? ? ???? ?’? ????? ??

?’? ????? ?? ??? ??? ??? ???? ????? ???? ?? ???

And if you solve this then you know where I would be

And I'll be solving riddles all day long with you

Now if I ???? for ??? ???? south

And turn right then ???? ??? ???? ????

I just need to ???? north an extra ????

To end up where I was ??????

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first six lines of this puzzle are an obfuscation of...

> ...the lyrics to the song *I'm Gonna Be (500 Miles)* by [The Proclaimers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Proclaimers):
>
>  When I wake up, *well I know I'm gonna be
>
>  I'm gonna be the man who wakes up next to you*
>  When I go out, *yeah, I know I'm gonna be
>
>  I'm gonna be the man who goes along with you*
>  If I get drunk, *well, I know I'm gonna be
>
>  I'm gonna be the man who gets drunk next to you*

All of this is intended to imply that the remainder of the riddle has relevance to:

> **walking**. (Because the lyrics to the chorus are "But I would *walk* 500 miles, And I would *walk* 500 more, Just to be the man who *walks* a thousand miles, To fall down at your door.") And specifically, to a very famous puzzle involving walking (and miles) which is presented here in the continued rhyme scheme. We can fill in its blanks as follows:
>
>  Now if I **walk** for **one mile** south
>  And turn right then **walk one mile more**
>  I just need to **walk** north an extra **mile**
>  To end up where I was **before**

As discussed elsewhere (including [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/rescue-operation-where-is-your-partner) on Puzzling!), this puzzle commonly has two acceptable solutions:

> You either start:
>
>  A) At the North Pole
>
>  [image: Solution 1]
>
>  or B) 1 mile north of a circle around the South Pole of circumference 1 mile
>
>  [image: Solution 2]
>  <sub>*Images courtesy of Michael Stillwell at [popularmechanics.com](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/math/a25018/solution-to-riddle-of-the-week-14/)*</sub>

However, as @LieutenantZipp points out in comments, this second case can be generalised:

> You could equally be at such a distance from the South Pole that walking 1 mile south puts you on a circle with circumference $\frac{1}{n}$ miles for some integer $n$. Walking 1 mile parallel to the equator then just involves walking the length of that circle $n$ times, which will still be a distance of 1 mile in total and bring you back to your starting point, and thus has the same end result. (Case B above is the scenario where $n=1$)

Comment: If Weird Al Yankovic wrote Riddles that were too easy ... well done! :-)

Comment: Technically, you could also rot13(or ng fhpu n qvfgnapr sebz gur Fbhgu Cbyr gung jnyxvat bar zvyr fbhgu chgf lbh ba n pvepyr cnenyyry gb gur rdhngbe jvgu enqvhf 1/a sbe fbzr vagrtre a. Gura lbh whfg jnyx nebhaq gur pvepyr zber gvzrf).

Comment: @LieutenantZipp Fair point. I've added the general case to my answer, thanks :)

Comment: That's not strictly the same: arne gur cbyr, urnqvat pbagvahnyyl jrfg (be rnfg) vf qvssrerag sebz znxvat n ghea naq gura jnyxvat va n fgenvtug yvar (terng pvepyr).  But that's a problem with the question, not the answer.